# Year of date validation is failing

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to do a date validation to accept it in dd/mm/yyyy format. However all conditions are working fine except that if I enter year of 6 digits it is also accepting it, like -

**12/12/200000**

as per my code is valid. Below is my code:

```
function validate(value) {
            if(!value.match(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d/))
                return false;
            return checkdate(value);
}

function checkdate(val)
{
    var dates = val.split(/\D/);
    if(dates[0] <= 0 || dates[0] > 31)
        return false;
    if(dates[1] <= 0 || dates[1] > 12)
        return false;
    var now = new Date(dates[2],dates[1]-1,dates[0]);
    if (isNaN(now))
        return false;
    now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (now.getFullYear() == dates[2] && now.getMonth() + 1 == dates[1] && now.getDate() == dates[0])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I am not sure why it allowing year as 6 digits valid input?

Comment: Your split is probably not right. Nothing will match your split

Comment: But the reg exp should not allow the code till that point

Comment: Create a regexp like this `var regExp = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/` then check it with match() function, then you dont have to create any extra function to check for the validity of each filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not limiting the regex with start and stop delimiters, so `12/12/200000` is a match as it matched the regex, and then some

```
if (!value.match(/^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d$/) )
```

As a sidenote, you don't have to type `\d` four times, you can do `\d{4}` to match four instances of `\d`

Comment: Thanks changing the reg exp as per your suggestion solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `validate` function, regular expression it matches against allows input values you don't want to pass as valid. Besides obvious `dd/mm/yyyy` format, it allows found text to be anywhere in string. Basically, you said for it to check "if there's said expression inside string", when it should have been "if the whole string matches this expression".

To fix the issue, add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. `^` stands for string start and `$` for string end:

`/^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d$/`

I think you would benefit from reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on regular expression syntax used by JavaScript.

While at at, humans tend to have issues reading long repeating sequences of similar characters, like in your regexp. This expression is easer to understand and does exactly the same thing:

`/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a date string by creating a Date object, you don't need to check the entire pattern, just create and Date and check the result. Do you really need two digits for day and month number?

If you want a 4 digit year, that must be checked separately as the constructor will happily convert two digit years to 20th century. If you *really* need two digit day and month, that can be checked at the same time as the year:

```
function validateDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && /^\d{4}$/.test(b[2]) && b[1] == d.getMonth();
}

console.log(validateDMY('30/02/2015')); // false
console.log(validateDMY('30/22/2015')); // false
console.log(validateDMY('02/02/15'));   // false
console.log(validateDMY('30/01/2015')); // true
```